# Access 2013: Getting error message "Method 'Open' of object' _Recordset' failed " when trying to populate text boxes with data in a form

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, recordset

I'm having an issue with this piece of VBA code. I'm trying to populate text boxes on a form in Access 2013 with data from a table called Module. Once a user selects an available module from a combo box and clicks a button called 'btnSelectmodule', the relevant data should feed into the text boxes. Instead I'm getting an error; " Method 'Open' of object' _Recordset' failed "

```
Private Sub btnSelectmodule_Click()

Dim strmoduleid As String
Dim rstmodule As New ADODB.Recordset

strmoduleid = CVar(cmbSelectmodule)

rstmodule.Open "SELECT Module.ModuleID, Module.ModuleName, 
Module.ModuleShortCode, Module.Level, Module.Semester, Module.CATPoints,
Module.FacultyCode, Module.Active, Module.Type FROM [Module] 
WHERE (((CVar([ModuleID]))='" & CVar(strmoduleid) & "'));", 
CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

If (rstmodule("ModuleID") <> "") Then

txtmoduleid.Value = rstmodule("ModuleID")
txtmodulename.Value = rstmodule("ModuleName")
txtmoduleshortcode.Value = rstmodule("ModuleShortCode")
cmblevel.Value = rstmodule("Level")
cmbsemester.Value = rstmodule("Semester")
cmbcatpoints.Value = rstmodule("CATPoints")
Active.Value = rstmodule("Active")
txttype.Value = rstmodule("Type")

End If

End Sub
```

This code works perfectly on three of my other forms. They populate data from different tables though. Could the problem have anything to do with the table being called Module? Because I've used [ ] in the SQL statement but still no joy? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the SQL string, you need to either :

a) change your table name to not be a keyword

b) surround all references in the SQL to Module with square brackets

c) use an alias: Select m.* FROM [Module] as m

d) change your table name to not be a keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was facing this issue, turned out that my table name was a keyword which was causing all this issue.